Is the Maximum Coverage Problem Remains as Hard when Taking Most Sets?
In the maximum coverage problem (also known as max k-cover) we are given a universe $U = \{e_1,\ldots, e_n\}$ of elements, a collection $F = \{S_1,\ldots, S_m\} \subseteq 2^U$ of sets over $U$, and an integer parameter $k$. The goal is to find $k$ sets $G \subseteq F, |G| = k$ such that the cardinality of $\bigcup_{S \in G} S$ is maximized (maximizing the number of elements taken). By the celebrated work of Feige [1], maximum coverage cannot be approximated to a better ratio than (roughly) $(1-1/e)$. However, it seems that the lower bound of [1] uses values of k such that $k \ll m$. Does the problem become easier if $m-k \leq k$? e.g., what is the strongest lower bound when $k = 0.9 \cdot m$? Or, what is the strongest lower bound as a function of $r = \frac{k}{m-k}$?
Any answer or pointer would be highly appreciated.
[1] Feige, U. 1998. A Threshold of ln n for Approximating Set Cover. Journal of the ACM, Vol. 45, No. 4, July 1998.

If $k = 0.9m$ then a random selection of $k$ subsets will cover a $0.9$ fraction of the universe, and so will be a $0.9$ approximation.

This is true, but is there still some lower bound?

Yuval's observation implies that there cannot be a lower bound (i.e. hardness result) better than $0.9 m$.  In other words, the answer to your question "Does the problem become easier if $m-k \le k$?" is 'yes'.   What kind of lower bound do you want?

Max Coverage is APX-Hard when $k \ge cm$ for some fixed constant $c < 1$ via reductions from bounded degree instances of 3D Matching etc. By adding dummy sets with singleton elements it seems that one can show APX hardness even when $k \simeq (1-\delta)m$ but the hardness goes down with $\delta$.
